# How to add a blog (blog.html) to my nonblog "jekyll" website (index.html)?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jekyll, blogs

## Situation:

I started of with a one scroll website from a bootstrap template.

I have figured how to add another page & navigating between home page and second page. Now I want to build a blog on this second page.

So far I have only seen tutorials that explain you how to set up a jekyll blog with a blog theme, rooting from `index.html`.

Yet

Now that I want to build a blog from `blog.html` Where do I start if I want my blogpage be looking just like this?
 https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-blog-post/?#

## Main Question

How do I link `2017-11-12-first_post.md` from root `_posts` to `blog.html`?

**Link to website:** http://werkbaar.net/

**Link to repo:** https://github.com/bomengeduld/boilerplate

Comment: just add a new menu item and link it to blog.html

Answer (score 1):

In the blog layout you should loop over the posts, like this:

```
{% for item in site.posts %}
  {{ item.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Link the new layout in the front matter of the blog.md file, like this:

```
---
title: Blog
layout: blog
---
```

The layout is a file called blog.html and should be placed in the _layouts directory. The blog.md file should be placed in the root of your project.

If you want only the first post to show, use `limit:1`:

```
{% for item in site.posts limit:1 %}
  {{ item.title }}
{% endfor %}
```